# How to find span of control from a hierarchical data in Go programming language

Tags: algorithm, go

Span of control refers to the number of people reporting to a manager both directly and indirectly(i.e., including the number of people reporting to the people reporting to him/her up until down below where the member has no one reporting to him/her) to know the full size of the team in his/her org structure.

I've put an implementation below. It gives the correct result But, I'm not sure if this is the best way really. I'm a novice. Can some one please recommend a better way to achieve this in Go language? Probably a more elegant approach, if possible. Thanks in advance!

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    orgData := []EmpRecord{
        {"E123", "Annapurna", "E456", "Ananya"},
        {"E789", "Arya", "E234", "Manisha"},
        {"E345", "Madhura", "E456", "Ananya"},
        {"E456", "Ananya", "E234", "Manisha"},
        {"E567", "Bharat", "E123", "Annapurna"},
        {"E678", "Shart", "E789", "Arya"},
        {"E101", "Akash", "E123", "Annapurna"},
        {"E102", "Anil", "E789", "Arya"},
        {"E103", "Vikas", "E123", "Annapurna"},
        {"E104", "Vivek", "E123", "Annapurna"},
        {"E105", "Ankita", "E456", "Ananya"},
        {"E106", "Atul", "E123", "Annapurna"},
        {"E107", "Priya", "E789", "Arya"},
        {"E234", "Manisha", "E999", "Albert"},
    }

    socList := make(map[string]int)
    var ix int = 0

    soc(orgData, socList, &ix)

    fmt.Println(socList)

}

type EmpRecord struct {
    EmpId   string
    EmpName string
    SupId   string
    SupName string
}

func soc(m []EmpRecord, socList map[string]int, rc *int) {
    for _, v := range m {
        _, ok := socList[v.SupId]
        if !ok {
            loopRecurive(v.SupId, m, rc)
            if *rc > 0 {
                socList[v.SupId] = *rc
                *rc = 0
            }
        }
    }

}

func loopRecurive(v string, er []EmpRecord, rc *int) {
    for _, x := range er {
        if v == x.SupId {
            *rc++
            loopRecurive(x.EmpId, er, rc)
        }
    }
}
```

The final output prints `map[E123:5 E234:13 E456:8 E789:3 E999:14]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can some one please recommend a better way...

"better way" can mean many things including:

- Quicker
- Lower memory use
- Easier to understand/maintain

As such your question is subjective; we can show you other ways of doing this but cannot really say that they are "better". Below is one alternative approach that I feel is easier to understand ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KKshk5Ephf3)).

```
package main

import "fmt"

type EmpRecord struct {
    EmpId   string
    EmpName string
    SupId   string
    SupName string
}

type EmpWithReports struct {
    EmpRecord
    Reports []*EmpWithReports
}

func main() {

    orgData := []EmpRecord{
        {"E123", "Annapurna", "E456", "Ananya"},
        {"E789", "Arya", "E234", "Manisha"},
        {"E345", "Madhura", "E456", "Ananya"},
        {"E456", "Ananya", "E234", "Manisha"},
        {"E567", "Bharat", "E123", "Annapurna"},
        {"E678", "Shart", "E789", "Arya"},
        {"E101", "Akash", "E123", "Annapurna"},
        {"E102", "Anil", "E789", "Arya"},
        {"E103", "Vikas", "E123", "Annapurna"},
        {"E104", "Vivek", "E123", "Annapurna"},
        {"E105", "Ankita", "E456", "Ananya"},
        {"E106", "Atul", "E123", "Annapurna"},
        {"E107", "Priya", "E789", "Arya"},
        {"E234", "Manisha", "E999", "Albert"},
    }

    empMap := make(map[string]*EmpWithReports)
    for _, emp := range orgData {
        empMap[emp.EmpId] = &EmpWithReports{EmpRecord: emp}
    }
    // Add reports for each employee
    for _, e := range empMap {
        if boss := empMap[e.SupId]; boss != nil {
            boss.Reports = append(boss.Reports, e)
        } else if e.SupId != "E999" {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("Employee %s: Boss %s not found", e.EmpId, e.SupId))
        }
    }

    // Get the counts
    socList := make(map[string]int)
    for _, e := range empMap {
        s := soc(empMap, e)
        if s > 0 {
            socList[e.EmpId] = s
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(socList)

}

func soc(empMap map[string]*EmpWithReports, emp *EmpWithReports) int {
    var s int
    for _, rep := range emp.Reports {
        s += 1 + soc(empMap, rep)
    }
    return s
}
```

The results are `map[E123:5 E234:13 E456:8 E789:3]` (`E999` is not included because they are not in the list; this would be simple to add if required).

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive solution with thought provoking question. Though this definitely provided a more readable approach, for which I upvoted as well, nevertheless your question made me think a level further. If I were to ask you what would be most optimal solution w.r.t. speed & memory, what would that be? since large data sets with so much recursion may tend to take lot of time.

Comment: These would be two different solutions. For instance you can solve this without any maps or recursion (keep looping looking for new underlings until you complete a full iteration without finding anything new); this will use little memory but lots of cpu cycles.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an algorithmic problem than language-specific. The hierarchical data follows a tree structure.

If you see the relationship's here will be something like `Employee has one leader` and `leader can have more than one direct-reportees`. If we build a tree-like structure this will be easier.

Tree Node Structure

```
type EmpRecord struct {
    EmpId   string
    EmpName string
    reportees     *EmpRecord[]
}
```

Note that you will have to create the `rootNode first` that will be the CEO or head of the department.

Now in order to find all the direct reportees you can use `Breadth-First` approach to find employees by level or `depth-first-approach` to find all the direct-indirect reporters with no specific ordering.

Note: You will need to know the address of the node corresponding to a particular employee. You can use a hashmap s.t `[empName] => [pointer to employeeRecord]` or whichever key works.

Note:- If you want to search the other way. From employees to all his manager's you can create two-way tree structure. Where you will also keep pointer to the superior with the node.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is definitely a great answer since this pushed me to think from algorithmic approaches.